# Mariadb: SQL Access denied for user 'root'@'%'

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, amazon-rds

## DB details

Using MariaDB on AWS.

**I am unable to give privileges to a user using the root account of mariadb**

> **My root user:**

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+-------------------+----------------+
| USER()            | CURRENT_USER() |
+-------------------+----------------+
| root@173.14.57.96 | root@%         |
+-------------------+----------------+
```

> **My root privileges:**

```
show grants for 'root'@'%';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, 
INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, 
REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, 
ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 
PASSWORD '<password>' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am still unable to give any access to any of the user.

> ERROR :

```
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `prod_db`.* TO 'prod_user'@'%';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'prod_db'
> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

try to add one more user 'root'@'localhost'. I often had the problem that the access for any host ('%') doesn't work if there is no correspondent account for localhost. So by default I meanwhile always add both by default.